# Connecting Local DB to DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm exploring Dbeaver as a DB client. I have a Postgres DB stored natively that I wish to connect to, using Dbeaver (the DB is a bunch of text files containing the various tables, a ToC file explaining the various relationships, and a SQL script for rebuilding the DB on a DB client). I even customized the SQL script that came with that DB, to work on my computer's filesystem. After spending lots of time on the manual, eventually, I decided to seek assistance here.

Any help on how to load/restore that DB would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: ...that sounds suspiciously like you don't have Postgres installed?

Comment: How do you run that SQL script? What is the error you get?

Comment: I tried it in two ways:
1. in the SQL browser of an existing sample SQLlite database that came with Dbeaver. One of the commands wasn't recognized by the SQLlite parser.
2. on a separate SQL browser window, attached to a Postgres database I've initiated. In this case, there was no connection to the database (I tried several times to get it to connect, without any luck).
Thanks for your clarification question. I should have included this info in the original question. Cheers

Comment: @Tomalak, I've already installed the latest Postgres on my system.